# How are the tag definitions (or descriptions) used on Stack Overflow generated?

Tags: support, tags

How does stackoverflow.com get the tag definitions? Are all the used tags defined by users,  administrators, or do they get their definitions from Wikipedia or somewhere else? 
By definition I mean the description of a tag which pops up when you hover a tag.

Comment: Click the *info* link on the popbox.

Answer (score 2):

Each tag potentially has a "tag wiki" associated with it, that is shown when you click on the tag. Anyone can edit a tag wiki; you can earn the privilege of approving the edits by getting 5000 reputation.